# Save order before submit

Tags: onepage-checkout

A client I'm working for wants to have order saved right after entering payment information (one page checkout). The status should be 'during_payment', but the status is not a problem. The problem is I don't know how to save order after that step, and then make magento just update the existing order with new payment information and status in case the payment succeded. Any ideas would be very welcome! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't make sense.

All informations you would save are already saved in the quote. So if he needs anything, just get it from the quote.

Comment: I agree that it doesn't make sense, but they want it that way and client is always right..

Comment: No they are not. Clients sell things. Your job is to implement workflows and processes not stupid ideas from clients. Ask him, what he wants to achieve and then implement it the best way you can.